# Having trouble getting certain refsections to print

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm putting together a CV and have a section for technical reports, but am having trouble getting this section, and certain other sections, to be included in the output document.

```
\begin{refsection} % This is a custom heading for those references marked as "Technical Report" 
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[sorting=chronological, type=techreport, title={technical reports}, keyword={Technical Report}, heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}
```

I definitely have a `techreport` listed in my `.bib` file:

```
@article{Natarajan2011,
author = {Natarajan, Nagarajan and Singh-Blom, Ulf Martin and Tewari, Ambuj and Woods, John O and Dhillon, Inderjit S and Marcotte, Edward M},
file = {:Users/jwoods/Downloads/Papers/Natarajan2011.pdf:pdf},
journal = {UTCS Technical Report},
title = {{Predicting gene\textendash disease associations using multiple species data.}},
volume = {TR-11-37},
year = {2011},
type = {techreport},
keyword = {Technical Report}
```

I've tried using the `keyword` and `type` parameters independently, but it's not working for me. Oddly, the technical report shows up in the `article` section instead, even though I've been careful to exclude technical reports:

```
\begin{refsection} % Articles that aren't in preparation
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[sorting=chronological, type=article, title={articles}, notkeyword={In Preparation}, notkeyword={Technical Report}, heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}
```

It also seems to ignore my `\DeclareBibliographyDriver` commands in some cases, e.g., for my dissertation:

```
\RequirePackage[style=verbose, maxnames=99, sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[patent]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[phdthesis]{title}{#1\par}

%
% ... other declarations, which do work ...
%

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{phdthesis}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}%
    \printfield{title}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    %\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    %\printlist{location}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}
```

Instead, it prints in standard format of author, title, when I clearly indicated title on one line and author on the next.

It seems like I must be misunderstanding the `\printbibliography` commands somehow. Can anyone help me to correct this misapprehension?

Answer (score 1):

Three mistakes!.

1. The `\printbibliography` option (key) `type`  is not to filter the entries by field `type`, is to print the bibitem by `entry names`. it means, `@book`, `@article`, etc... (without `@`). The example bibentry is a `@article` if it is changed to `@techreport` it works if the `type` option (`\printbibliography`) is *report*.

For filter by field (different to keywords) you can use `check` option and `\defbibcheck`. For example, to filter by `type` equals to *techreport*.

```
\defbibcheck{techreport}{%
\iffieldundef{type}
 {\skipentry}
 {\iffieldequalstr{type}{techreport}
    {}
    {\skipentry}}}
```

and

`\printbibliography[check=techreport]`

2. The bibtex field is `keywords` not *keyword*. The example bibtex entry is using *keyword*.
3. By default `biblatex`not use the entry `phdthesis`. It uses the `thesis` entry for `phdthesis` and `mastersthesis`. And it is possible use the `type` field to choices if the entry is `masterthesis` or `phdthesis`. When is defined a `entry` with `@pdfthesis`, `biblatex` 'convert' it to `thesis` entry and define the `type` field to *phdthesis*.

In the example in the question it is necessary to redefine the `thesis` driver and declare the `title` format of `thesis` entry.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{#1\par}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{thesis}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \printfield{title}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[style=authoryear, maxnames=99]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{MWE.bib}
    @techreport{Natarajan2011,
    author = {Natarajan, Nagarajan and Singh-Blom, Ulf Martin and Tewari, Ambuj and Woods, John O and Dhillon, Inderjit S and Marcotte, Edward M},
    file = {:Users/jwoods/Downloads/Papers/Natarajan2011.pdf:pdf},
    journal = {UTCS Technical Report},
    title = {{Predicting gene\textendash disease associations using multiple species data.}},
    volume = {TR-11-37},
    year = {2011},
    type = {techreport},
    keywords = {Technical Report}}

    @phdthesis{thesis000,
    author = {Author Name},
    title = {Title of the thesis},
    type= {phdthesis},
    year = {2011}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{MWE.bib}

\defbibcheck{techreport}{%
\iffieldundef{type}
 {\skipentry}
 {\iffieldequalstr{type}{techreport}
    {}
    {\skipentry}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{#1\par}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{thesis}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \printfield{title}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection} 
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[type=report,title=Printing the {\it reports} entries]
\printbibliography[check=techreport,title=Filtering by {\it type} field equals to techreport]
\printbibliography[keyword=Technical Report,title=Filtering by keyword]
\printbibliography[title=Editing the {\it thesis} driver, type=thesis]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]